# Opencv: Trying to change the background of image

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I have created an image in which i am drawing a line straight line using opencv, 
this is my code

```
 #include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
    #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "opencv/cv.h"
    #include "opencv/highgui.h"
    int main()
    { 
    int y[200]; 
          int x=0; 
      for(x=50;x<150;x++)
      {
          y[x]=43;
      }
      IplImage *grf = cvCreateImage( cvSize( 200, 200), 8, 3 );
      for( x=50;x<150;x++)
      {
      cvLine(grf ,                         
              cvPoint(x, y[x]),  
               cvPoint(x+1, y[x]),            
               CV_RGB(255, 255, 255),      
               1, 8, 0);                    
      }
      cvNamedWindow("img", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        cvShowImage("img", grf);
        cvWaitKey(0);
        cvDestroyWindow("img");
        cvReleaseImage(&grf);
    return 0;
    }
```

I want to change my image background as white and want line in black color.
please help me.

Answer (score 1):

To make a black line change your cvLine to:

```
  cvLine(grf ,                         
          cvPoint(x, y[x]),  
           cvPoint(x+1, y[x]),            
           CV_RGB(0,0,0),      
           1, 8, 0);                    
  }
```

To change your background to white:

```
cvSet(img, CV_RGB(255,255,255);
```

On an aside:

you should stop using the C api and use cv::Mat, the c API is deprecated and unsupported.